# Dependency injection in singleton

Tags: c#

I'm working on unlocking feature:

```
public class UnlockManager
{
    private static UnlockManager instance;
    public static UnlockManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new UnlockManager();
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }

    private ProductsList products;

    private Regex rxConfetti;
    private Regex rxWhiteSpace;

    private UnlockManager()
    {
        rxConfetti = new Regex(
         ".*",
         RegexOptions.Multiline |
         RegexOptions.CultureInvariant |
         RegexOptions.Compiled);

        rxWhiteSpace = new Regex(
         "\\s",
         RegexOptions.Multiline |
         RegexOptions.CultureInvariant |
         RegexOptions.Compiled);


        string confetti = DecodeConfetti(LoadConfetti());
        products = ProductsList.FromConfetti(confetti);
    }   

    public bool IsAtLeastOneGroupUnlocked
    {
        get
        {
            bool result = false;

            Group.Entry[] groups = Group.Entry.GetList();
            foreach (Group.Entry group in groups) {
                if (IsGroupUnlocked(group.Id)) {
                    result = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }

    public bool IsGroupUnlocked(int groupId)
    {
        return IsUnlocked(groupId,
                  (productName, test) => {
                      return productName == test.Abbreviation;
                  });
    }

    private bool IsUnlocked(int groupId, Func<string, Test.Entry, bool> predicate)
    {
        if (products.HasItems) {
            Test.Entry[] tests = Test.Entry.GetListByGroupId(groupId);

            foreach (Test.Entry test in tests) {
                foreach (Dictionary<string, string> item in products.Items) {
                    if (item.ContainsKey("PRODUCT")) {
                        string productName = item["PRODUCT"]
                                                     .Trim()
                                                     .ToUpperInvariant();

                        if (predicate(productName, test) == true) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }   

    public void ProcessConfetti(string confettiContainer)
    {
        if (IsValidConfetti(confettiContainer)) {
            string confetti = ExtractConfetti(confettiContainer);

            UpdateProductsAndSaveConfetti(confetti);
        }
    }

    public bool IsValidConfetti(string confetti)
    {
        bool result = false;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(confetti)) {
            result = rxConfetti.IsMatch(confetti);
        }

        return result;
    }

    private void UpdateProductsAndSaveConfetti(string confetti)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(confetti)) {
            products = ProductsList.FromConfetti(DecodeConfetti(confetti));
            SaveConfetti(confetti);
        }
    }

    private void SaveConfetti(string confetti)
    {
        GetRegistryKey()
            .SetValue("REG", confetti);
    }

    private string LoadConfetti()
    {
        return GetRegistryKey()
                    .GetValue("REG", string.Empty)
                    .ToString();
    }

    private string ExtractConfetti(string confettiContainer)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;

        var match = rxConfetti.Match(confettiContainer);

        if (match != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(match.Value)) {
            result = rxWhiteSpace.Replace(match.Groups["confetti"].Value, string.Empty);
        }

        return result;
    }

    private string DecodeConfetti(string confetti)
    {
        return confetti
                .FromHex()

    }

    private RegistryKey GetRegistryKey()
    {

        return Registry.CurrentUser
                            .CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE")
                            .CreateSubKey("Application")
                            .CreateSubKey("REG");

    }
}
```

I don't like it because I cannot inject registry dependency in that singleton implementation. Do you have some advice on how to make it better?

Comment: Is your application single threaded? Why do you want to inject the registry?

Comment: One solution would be to use a DI container (such as Castle Windsor or Automap) you configure the class as singleton there and use usual injection techniques.

Comment: You could have some generic persistence class which you inject, which implements an interface's Load/Save methods. So you could inject the version which internally loads from/saves to the registry, or a fake for unit testing.

Comment: Let the Di Container control the instance lifetime

Comment: @eurotrash, yes, it is exactly what I want to do, but I don't know how properly I can inject it in the unlocking manager instance, before it will be created.

Comment: @L3xer That's one of the problems with singletons. I never use them anymore, though I often construct classes with singleton "lifestyles". As another answer pointed out, if this class must be a singleton then you can use property injection.

Comment: Please do not add, remove, or edit code in a question after you've received an answer. The site policy is explained in [What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). (I don't have full edit permissions yet, so someone else needs to rollback to version 1)

Comment: @Sumurai8 done :) You can always suggest a rollback, it should pass through the suggested edits queue just fine

Comment: @Vogel612 The edit history does not show the rollback link. I would either need to copy the raw source of revision 1, then paste that in the edit field, or manually remove the updates. Both are prone to errors, so I leave it to someone that can simply push that button where it automatically just... works.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any advice for dependency injection, but I see some other improvements you can make.  These changes require `using System.Linq;`.

In `IsAtLeastOneGroupUnlocked`, you can replace most of the code by using `Enumberable.Any()`:

```
public bool IsAtLeastOneGroupUnlocked
{
    get
    {
        Group.Entry[] groups = Group.Entry.GetList();
        return groups.Any(x => IsGroupUnlocked(x.Id));
    }
}
```

In `IsGroupUnlocked()`, the lambda expression only needs to be written the way you wrote it if you want to have multiple lines of code in the body.  A simpler way to write it is like this:

```
return IsUnlocked(groupId, (productName, test) => productName == test.Abbreviation);
```

In `IsUnlocked()`, you can get the product names before the loop and loop through those instead of looping through dictionaries, filtering, and then getting a product name each iteration:

```
string[] productNames = products.Items
    .Where(x => x.ContainsKey("PRODUCT"))
    .Select(x => x["PRODUCT"].Trim().ToUpperInvariant())
    .ToArray();
```

You can then use `Enumberable.Any()` to find any combination of productName and test that matches the predicate.

```
private bool IsUnlocked(int groupId, Func<string, Test.Entry, bool> predicate)
{
    if (!products.HasItems)
    {
        return false;
    }

    Test.Entry[] tests = Test.Entry.GetListByGroupId(groupId);
    string[] productNames = products.Items
        .Where(x => x.ContainsKey("PRODUCT"))
        .Select(x => x["PRODUCT"].Trim().ToUpperInvariant())
        .ToArray();
    return tests.Any(x => productNames.Any(y => predicate(y, x)));
}
```

The main reason to have a `Func` as a parameter is so you can specify different predicates.  If there's only one predicate you'll be passing in you might as well just move that logic inside the method and remove the `Func` parameter.  Then, in your case, you may convert the array of tests to an array of abbreviations of type string and use simpler logic for finding a common string in two arrays.  `Enumerable.Intersect()` looks at two collections and returns the items that are in both.  Then you return true if the intersection has any items.

```
private bool IsUnlocked(int groupId)
{
    if (!products.HasItems)
    {
        return false;
    }

    Test.Entry[] tests = Test.Entry.GetListByGroupId(groupId);
    string[] abbreviations = tests.Select(x => x.Abbreviation).ToArray();
    string[] productNames = products.Items
        .Where(x => x.ContainsKey("PRODUCT"))
        .Select(x => x["PRODUCT"].Trim().ToUpperInvariant())
        .ToArray();
    return abbreviations.Intersect(productNames).Any();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do Dependency Injection using property injection instead.

Here is a quick example:

```
public class ServiceA : IServiceA
{
    [Dependency]
    public IServiceB ServiceB { get; set; };

    public string MethodA1()
    {
        return "MethodA1() " +serviceB.MethodB1();
    }
}
```

DI with UNity: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463(v=pandp.30).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer about IOC Container, seems I've found the best solution for me.

I've created the interface that I want to inject

```
public interface IConfettiRepository
{
    void Save(string confetti);
    string Load();        
}
```

And registry implementation

```
class RegistryConfettiRepository : IConfettiRepository
{
    public string Load()
    {
        return GetRegistryKey()
                   .GetValue("REG", string.Empty)
                   .ToString();
    }

    public void Save(string confetti)
    {
         GetRegistryKey()
              .SetValue("REG", confetti);
    }

    private RegistryKey GetRegistryKey()
    {
         return Registry.CurrentUser
                            .CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE")
                            .CreateSubKey("Application")
                            .CreateSubKey("REG");
    }
}
```

Register UnlockManager with its dependency

```
TinyIoCContainer.Current.Register(new UnlockManager(new RegistryConfettiRepository()));
```

And then modified instance getter

```
private IConfettiRepository confettiRepository;

 public static UnlockManager Instance
 {
     get
     {
        return TinyIoCContainer.Current.Resolve<UnlockManager>();
     }
 }

 public UnlockManager(IConfettiRepository confettiRepository)
 {
     this.confettiRepository = confettiRepository;

     ...
 }
```

Comment: FYI - this is called "service locator" and is generally considered an [anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/).